Writing file content directly to user space
When reading the content of a file using a syscall like read,
why does the kernel first copy it to a kernel buffer
and then to user space, instead of directly copying it to user space?
I understand that by doing so, the kernel can perform caching and read-ahead, but I want to know if there is any architectural decision that restricts the kernel from directly piping the file content to user space.

Note that if you're bothered by the extra copy, you can just mmap() the file instead of calling read(). That's your "direct copy to userspace" right there, supported by all major OSes for decades.

@TooTea Also, for certain use cases, sendfile(). And there may be other APIs for "zero-copy" I/O that I'm not aware of.

Part of the reason is that physical disk I/O usually occurs in whole blocks,
where block sizes are typically 512 bytes or a multiple thereof
(specifically, AFAIK, typically a power of 2 times 512). 
The design of the read and write system calls allows processes
to read and write data in arbitrary increments; e.g., single bytes.

That could only work if you'd be able to instruct a device to directly DMA to a user buffer. Typically, you don't want to do that. (And there's technical measures (IOMMU) to make it impossible that arbitrary devices can write to arbitrary memory, as that's a huuuuge security problem.)
Also, it assumes that the kernel doesn't have to look at the data read from the storage. That's usually not the case – file system information, integrity/checksums, cryptography and the fact that reads might neither be sized correctly nor buffers aligned correctly would make that impossible in the general case.

It is a thing, though, in limited scope – e.g. if RDMA allows programs to directly receive data from network to a userspace buffer, I'd be somewhat surprised if there really was no equivalent for local storage... even if not necessarily through regular read()/write() calls.

(1) Regarding direct DMA to a user buffer, you say, “Typically, you don't want to do that.”  Why not?  (2) Nobody’s talking about allowing devices to write to arbitrary memory.  The question is about directing a device to write to a buffer in user space, at the request of the user process that owns that memory.  (3) Do you say that that is “a huuuuge security problem”?  If so, why?  … (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) …  (4) “Also, it assumes that the kernel doesn't have to look at the data read from the storage.”  Well, yes, for the read system call, for “reading the content of a file” (emphasis added) into user space, that’s a perfectly reasonable assumption.

@grawity you ignore that for RDMA, you need to use special buffers, you cannot just take a pointer to some memory and pass it into read. It's a huge security problem because usually, you program some hardware (e.g. GPUs, network cards), that can be instructed to do memory transfers. If you now allow a user to affect that, that userland program might suddenly read and write to arbitrary addresses – not just these belonging to its own processes. That means that user being able to, with the device as intermediary, do arbitrary memory transfers can be more mighty than root, higher in privilege

than even kernel-mode code (because they're not bound by nested page tables and hence escape their VM) and do actual physical damage to their computer (e.g. overwriting firmware). This is the kind of things that was used to break into Nintendo switches, escape commercial hypervisors, and generally make it impossible to run a datacenter where you rent out parts of servers to other people.

(4) no, that's completely wrong, that's absolutely not a reasonable assumption, and I even listed multiple cases where that's not the case when reading a file where the assumption is wrong, in my answer.

(2) and if the hardware can't write to arbitrary memory, how do you propose it writes to memory belonging to a random userland process, which will not be a contiguous piece of physical memory? I think you're ignoring 90% of how memory works in modern computers.
